# Update Page on Database Change

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to update a UI element depending on a change in the database? For example, whenever someone comments on a post, Facebook automatically updates the element for each user - how is this done?

I know that data pulling is one way to do it but are there any better procedures?

I would like to know how something like this can be done with Python (Django) but any other generic solution is welcome as well.

Comment: You should be using ajax for your on page non-refresh activities; what you want can be done via sending the current page ajax requests; if anything changed refreshing the related part. It is not related to django and cannot be done via it.

Comment: Ajax will only update my page, but how it will be reflected in every user's page? is my understanding right?

Comment: What do you "your page"? For any user that is currently viewing the webpage, ajax would refresh the page when there is a new comment or whatever you are calling in your ajax.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol:

> WebSocket is a computer communications protocol, providing full-duplex
>   communication channels over a single TCP connection

and usually the default way to do with Django is to use the [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels) project:

> Channels augments Django to bring WebSocket, long-poll HTTP, task
>   offloading and other async support to your code, using familiar Django
>   design patterns and a flexible underlying framework that lets you not
>   only customize behaviours but also write support for your own
>   protocols and needs.

You will probably need to spend some time to configure the `channels` setup and modify your application to use it, but if you're looking to "push" data from backend to the frontend after a certain action has finished, this is probably the way to do it.

I would recommend looking into the [channels-examples](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples) repository for an example chat implementation which uses `django-channels`.